# How to associate a new external disk with complete Time Machine history

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, restore

I want to restore my external USB drive to a new drive from a Time Machine backup. I used `sudo tmutil associatedisk` as was suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261761/how-to-restore-a-time-machine-backup-of-a-usb-drive-to-a-new-usb-drive/262005#262005). The actual restoring worked well and I could also associate the new disk to the old backup, however I could only associate it to one snapshot at a time. A comment suggested using the `-a` flag, as per the `man` page:

```
thermopylae:~ thoth$ sudo tmutil associatedisk [-a]
"/Volumes/MyNewStuffDisk"
"/Volumes/Chronoton/Backups.backupdb/thermopylae/Latest/MyStuff"

The result of the above command would associate the volume store
MyStuff in the specified backup with the source volume
MyNewStuffDisk. The volume store would also be renamed to match.
The -a option tells associatedisk to find all volume stores in
the same machine directory that match the identity of MyStuff,
and then perform the association on all of them.
```

However I can't get it to work. When I run

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a "/Volumes/My Drive" "/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/My Macbook/Latest/My Drive"
```

I only get the usage message printed

```
Usage: tmutil associatedisk [-a] mount_point volume_backup_directory
A local volume mount point and a snapshot volume path are required.
```

I am sure that I used the correct `mount_point` and `volume_backup_directory`, because when I run the command without the `-a` flag the association works – with the caveat being that while I can view that specific snapshot of the drive when browsing Time Machine backups, the (new) drive is still not included when backing up.
I am out of ideas here, because I can not see my error in using the command and I can't seem to find anyone who has had a similar problem. Any ideas would be appreciated. I would like to keep the drive history, but if that is not possible (i.e. if I can only associate the most recent snapshot) then most importantly I need Time Machine to recognise that it should keep backing up this drive.

If this is important: As a last ditch idea I also tried using the command with `[-a]` instead of `-a` but that only yielded the result

```
zsh: no matches found: [-a]
```

with the backup then being un-associated again.

**Edit:** The external disk is formatted as `HFS+` (so is the Time Machine disk, as to my knowledge Time Machine does not work with APFS-formatted disks), I am using macOS Ventura 13.2.1 on an M2 MacBook Air.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out these details, I have edited them in :)

Comment: Please double check format of TM disk. The default format has been APFS for a few years. That would explain why your `associatedisk` fails.

Comment: Thanks @Gilby, I did double check, it is still formatted as `HFS+` (`MacOS Extended (Journaled)` is what it tells me, and that is `HFS+` if I am correctly informed. I have been using an older version of MacOS until recently and just upgraded last month, I might try upgrading the TM disk to APFS via Disk Utility if that might help?

Comment: You don't "upgrade" the TM disk from HFS+ to APFS. You reformat the whole disk as APFS.  If possible use a new external disk (formatted as APFS) and keep the old HFS+ in case you need to recover anything from the past.